Gulp does not create a folder in dist
Gulp cannot create an img folder in the dist folder. Everything goes
without errors, but the folder does not appear!
const srcPath = "src/"
    const distPath = "dist/"
    
    const path = {
        build: {
            html: distPath,
            css: distPath + "css",
            js: distPath + "js",
            images: distPath + "images",
            fonts: distPath + "fonts"
        },
        src: {
            html: srcPath + "*.html",
            css: srcPath + "scss/*.scss",
            js: srcPath + "js/*.js",
            images: srcPath + "images/**/*.(jpg, png, svg, gif, ico, webp)",
            fonts: "srcPath + font/**/*.(woff, woff2, eot, ttf, svg)"
        },
        watch: {
            html: srcPath + "**/*.html",
            css: srcPath + "scss/**/*.scss",
            js: srcPath + "js/**/*.js",
            images: srcPath + "images/**/*.(jpg, png, svg, gif, ico, webp)",
            fonts: "srcPath + font/**/*.(woff, woff2, eot, ttf, svg)"
        },
    
        clean: "./" + distPath
    }
    
    function images() {
        return src(path.src.images, { base: srcPath + "images/" })
    
            .pipe(imagemin(
                [
                    imagemin.gifsicle({ interlaced: true }),
                    imagemin.mozjpeg({ quality: 85, progressive: true }),
                    imagemin.optipng({ optimizationLevel: 5 }),
                    imagemin.svgo({
                        plugins: [
                            {
                                name: 'removeViewBox',
                                active: true
                            },
                            {
                                name: 'cleanupIDs',
                                active: false
                            }
                        ]
                    })
                ]
            ))
            .pipe(dest(path.build.images))
    
    }
    
    exports.images = images

I looked through the code, but didn’t find any errors in the names, I tried running the function without a plugin, the same result

It always to say which gulp version you are using?  gulp -v
